# Python-Sum Of Digits Raised to Powers

Tags: python

```
def sum_powers(x1, n1, x2, n2):

    """ Computes x1^n1+x2^n2
    x1,n1,x2,n2 -- numbers
    Use only call expressions,
    Not infix operators(+,-,...) """

    return __________________________
```

Does anyone know what I have to do here? I know which sum I am supposed to compute, but I do not really understand my teacher's instructions. Can someone help? 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: The instructions look pretty clear to me. Please be more specific about what the problem is here.

Comment: It sounds like they maybe want for you to use `operators.add`, maybe? If you want clarification on what your teacher means though, you should ask your teacher.

Comment: I am not sure what I am NOT supposed to use.

Comment: answer added , and for thoese who are down voting this question , please be nice , he is new with just 6 rep

Comment: Why are people downvoting the question? Did I do something wrong?

Comment: probably because it's homework with no research.

Comment: its home work but he is not asking to implement it for him, he just ask expert opinion what the instructor mean by call methods

Comment: your answer is at the proper level.

Comment: So, what should I do? If i write: def sum_powers(x1,n1,x2,n2): return sum(x1**n1,x2**n2) will it be correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to the best of my guess , the instructor wants you to use the dunder method format . like :  `__add__` , `__sub__` etc . in your code , so that you understand how python implements those operators , or which magic methods represent those operators.

```
Operator    Method
+   object.__add__(self, other)
-   object.__sub__(self, other)
*   object.__mul__(self, other)
//  object.__floordiv__(self, other)
/   object.__truediv__(self, other)
%   object.__mod__(self, other)
**  object.__pow__(self, other[, modulo])
<<  object.__lshift__(self, other)
>>  object.__rshift__(self, other)
&   object.__and__(self, other)
^   object.__xor__(self, other)
|   object.__or__(self, other)
```

**example ( can be done on other ways):**

```
def sum_powers(x1, n1, x2, n2):

    """ Computes x1^n1+x2^n2
    x1,n1,x2,n2 -- numbers
    Use only call expressions,
    Not infix operators(+,-,...) """

    p1 = x1.__pow__(n1)
    p2 = x2.__pow__(n2)

    return p1.__add__(p2)
```

Documentation [here](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_magic_methods.php)

Comment: it's probably the case. Now _why_ such idiotic exercises?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre its home work but he is not asking to implement it for him, he just ask expert opinion what the instructor mean by call methods , and probably people are unable to understand his situation and keep down voting his question , this kind of thing should not be the standard and values at stackoverflow

Comment: Maybe, just maybe, the OP is supposed to use the operators as offered by the `operator` module, so that he would have to make the priority of the operations and the order of execution explicit...

Comment: I think the excersise is just to make sure the student know about magic dunder methods used for built in operators , pretty much expected in every beginner python course

Comment: "pretty much expected in every beginner python course" probably not. Not very useful at first. anyway I hate those "_you can only use xxxx_ questions"

Comment: So, what do I do?

Comment: @M.Papapetros write the python code as usual to compute the sum , but replace the operators with dunder methods , answer updated

Comment: @M.Papapetros , see the answer

Comment: someone also suggested to use `operator` module. Which also matches the requirements too.